# Nativescript - creating a navigation history

Tags: nativescript

I've got an app - starts at page A navigates to page B.

Is it possible to set up an app to navigate to page B, the back button on that page navigates to A and pressing hardware BACK button again exits the app.

Basically simulating an app starts at A, user navigates to B and then back again.

Is it possible to create the back-stack navigation history?

Comment: This sounds like the default navigation stack in an android app. If so, yes this is out of the box how it works. If it's not working as described then I'm misunderstanding what you're asking :) Also, if you need to work with the nav `STACK` you can use the `ui/frame` module http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_frame_.html#stack and access the `stack` method to return an `Array<Frame>`

Comment: Clarification...on startup, sometimes I'd like the app to go to page B directly. So page A is not in nav history...but if the user pressed the back button, I'd like them to navigate to page A and pressing back again, exit the app as normal. IOW, I'd like to push page A in the history before navigating to page B.

Comment: Well in your app.js (app.ts), the entry point of your app, you can determine which page to send the user. For example, if they've previously authenticated and you store some key, just check for the key and then when you call the `.start()` method in the app.js point to the page/module you want the user to go to. Then you'd need to actually use the `ui/frame` module as I described initially to find out what frames are in the `stack` and then you should be able to `push()`, `pop`, `splice` on the array to add/remove frames from the stack. I've never tried manipulating the stack but should work.